# Web.config System.net connectionManagement generic address

Tags: asp.net, iis

In an ASP.NET project I am limiting the number of concurrent connections to an external web service using the following in my Web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="http://test.domain.com" maxconnection="1"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

The above works however I would like to limit all requests to *.domain.com using something like:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="http://*.domain.com" maxconnection="1"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

This does not work however, any ideas?

Comment: I can't try it out right now but aren't you allowed to use regular expressions in the `address` value? This would match all subdomains: `.*(?<!www).domain.com`

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: @jackwild old, but any luck?

Comment: @sonjz sorry I'm afraid not.